# Identify owner/creator of old bigquery tables

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, audit

I've been trying to identify the owners/creators of BigQuery tables across multiple projects in our organization. My first option was audit log, however, we only started sinking the audit logs to bigquery last 2021 and we're trying to identify tables created older than that (2015 onwards).

I've also tried checking the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS` for each of the projects. However, that seems to only have 180 days retention.

Does anyone has any ideas on other ways/approach to explore to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

There is another approach but in your case, it will be laborious since you want to identify the tables created from 2015 onwards.

You can browse by going to the `Project History` or `Personal History` in the BigQuery console. `Job ID`, `Creation Time`, `Owner`, `Type`, `Summary`, `Insights`, `Session ID`, and `Actions` are stated.

[image]

Note: It is only advisable for tracking recent jobs in BigQuery.

If you have any questions, please leave a comment.

Comment: This approach has a lot of manual steps which is going to be troublesome, especially, since I need to identify the table owners on org-wide (thousands of projects). Also, this has limited data. I could obtain more information from INFORMATION_SCHEMA and our existing org-wide audit log sink.